# Using d3.nest to create a pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nested, pie-chart

I have an assortment of data, and I have used it to create a donut chart. I want to make a pie chart using a breakdown of the data, which I've acquired using d3.nest to subdivide the data I had (it was currently in 3 categories: nest breaks it down into 129). Basically, I have Olympic data based on medals awarded, and I want to subdivide the data on interaction into which sports they were earned in.

I'm just not sure how to use nested data to create a pie chart, particularly if the keys are variable. I'll include my implementation for the donut chart.

```
  var pie = d3.pie();

  // color based on medal awarded
  // order: gold, silver, bronze
  var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(['#e5ce0c', '#e5e4e0', '#a4610a']);

  var arcs = d3.select(svg).selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + ((h-25)/2) + ")");

  arcs.append("path")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("stroke", "white")
  .style("stroke-width", "0.5px")
  .on('mouseover', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', .7);

  })
  .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr('opacity', 1);
  });

  // title
  d3.select(svg).append('text')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      return ((w/2) - 85);
    })
    .attr('y', '20')
    .text(function(d) {
      return ('Medal breakdown for ' + country);
    })
    .attr('font-size', '16px');

  arcs.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });
```

Comment: Can you please tell the structure of dataset you are using ?

Comment: It’s basically just a list of sport -> value, AKA the number of medals from that type

Comment: i have added a format to know the exact format you have? If not can you please post the format in your question as well. Because its difficult to understand like this and why you need to use d3.nest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please confirm is this the format of data you have ?

Please find the code below and let me know if you have any doubt.

```js
var w = 400;
var h = 400;
var r = h/2;
var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var data = [
{name:"football", medal:1},
{name:"hockey", medal:2},
{name:"cricket", medal:3},
{name:"tennis", medal:4},
{name:"table tennis", medal:5},
];


var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr("width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d){return d.medal;});

// declare an arc generator function
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

// select paths, use arc generator to draw
var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");
arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i){
        return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", function (d) {
        // log the result of the arc generator to show how cool it is :)
        return arc(d);
    });

// add the text
arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function(d){
   d.innerRadius = 0;
   d.outerRadius = r;
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";}).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text( function(d, i) {
    return data[i].name;}
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.15/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Yup, that's basically what it looks like! I'm passing it into the function as an argument and I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually use it.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please let me know if any questions.